# Getting a kivy app to update visible interface (no widgets)

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using kivy, and unable to get the kivy interface to update.

I've based the layout around a `current_node`, a dictionary entry that fills in the other variables. Ideally, the layout should depend on the current node.

When I run the app, `current_node` and all its child variables update in `MyApp` class, in the python code - but not on the kivy interface. Any ideas why?

Stuff I've tried that hasn't worked:

- Creating a separate class for the layout (can't dynamically change the number of buttons)
- Changing `update_node` function to include `MyApp.build()` (missing positional argument self)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
tree = {
    '0' : ['Hi!', 'A', 'B'],
    'A' : ['Yes', 'AA', 'AB','AC'],
    'AA': ['Seneca', 'AAA', 'AAB'],
    'AAA': ['Yes', 'AAA', 'AAB'],
    'AAB': ['No', 'AAA', 'AAB'],
    'AB' : ['Cato', "AA", "AB"],
    'AC' : ['Neither'],
    'B' : ["No",'BA','BB'],
    'BA': ['xx'],
    'BB': ['xxx']
}

class MyApp(App):
    current_node = '0'

    def update_node(self, *args):
        self.current_node = args[0]
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout()
        child_nodes = tree[self.current_node][1:]
        j = len(child_nodes)
        # Answer Buttons
        for i in child_nodes:
            answer_button = Button(
                    text=tree[i][0],
                    pos=(100, j*75),
                    size_hint = (0.8, 0.1),
                    )
            button_callback = partial(self.update_node, i)
            answer_button.bind(on_release=button_callback)
            layout.add_widget(answer_button)
            j -= 1
            print(i)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def update_node(self, *args):
    self.current_node = args[0]
    self.build()
```

`self.build()` - [is](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build) a method that App itself calls to get root widget. You shouldn't call it manually, you can't recreate things with it.

You should change childs of root widget instead:

```
from functools import partial

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


tree = {
    '0':   ['Hi!', 'A', 'B'],
    'A':   ['Yes', 'AA', 'AB','AC'],
    'AA':  ['Seneca', 'AAA', 'AAB'],
    'AAA': ['Yes', 'AAA', 'AAB'],
    'AAB': ['No', 'AAA', 'AAB'],
    'AB':  ['Cato', "AA", "AB"],
    'AC':  ['Neither'],
    'B':   ["No",'BA','BB'],
    'BA':  ['xx'],
    'BB':  ['xxx']
}


class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    current_node = '0'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._rebuild()

    def update_node(self, i, *args):
        self.current_node = i
        self._rebuild()

    def _rebuild(self, *args):
        self.clear_widgets()  # clear current buttons

        child_nodes = tree[self.current_node][1:]
        j = len(child_nodes)
        # Answer Buttons
        for i in child_nodes:
            answer_button = Button(
                pos=(100, j*75),
                size_hint=(0.8, 0.1),
                text=tree[i][0],
            )
            answer_button.bind(
                on_release=partial(self.update_node, i)
            )
            j -= 1
            print(i)
            self.add_widget(answer_button)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you! This explanation and example is very useful.